# BigQuery/SQL: Select first row of each group

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to select the first row of each group. Eg: below table I would want to keep product for www/edf/ and cate for www/abc/.

I have tried multiple ways, eg: ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [...]) but somehow not getting expected outputs. The challenge for me here is that category does not have numbers as values, otherwise I can filter it down using max or min.

```
SELECT landing_page,   ROW_NUMBER  OVER ( PARTITION BY landing_page ORDER BY Page_Type DESC) AS ROW_NUM
from `xxxx.TEST.draft`
```

However I got this error:  OVER keyword must follow a function call

Appreciate any help!

| Landing_page | Page_type |
| --- | --- |
| www/edf/ | product |
| www/edf/ | home |
| www/abc/ | cate |
| www/abc/ | home |

Comment: There needs to be some column(s) which provide the ordering logic for knowing which "first" record to retain per group.  Sans this, your question can't really be answered.

Comment: If you have tried `ROW_NUMBER()` and didn't get desired output, then please show your current code and describe what is wrong with its output. Because`ROW_NUMBER()` is a general way to select N rows per group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the function `[FIRST_VALUE][1]`?

```
SELECT 
    landing_page,   
    FIRST_VALUE(URL)  
        OVER ( PARTITION BY landing_page ORDER BY Page_Type DESC) AS first_url
FROM `xxxx.TEST.draft`
```

Comment: thank you @Cylldby ! I also tried using row_number() and it worked. I posted my query below if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question, sharing the code in case anyone needs:

```
SELECT session_id,landing_page, Page_Type, ROW_NUMBER ()  OVER (PARTITION BY session_id,landing_page ORDER BY Page_Type DESC) AS ROW_NUM
from `xxx._TEST.draft`
order by session_id desc
```